# history.pushState removing part of the url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement history.pushState into our website to replace hash bangs but I'm puzzled as to why every time I click on a link that instead of appending the href value onto the current url e.g. www.abc.com/123.php/20 it instead makes it www.abc.com/20 even though I am still on the 123.php page (hopefully that makes sense).

I should also point out the the html below is created via php.

I have read quite a few tutorials explaining how to implement this and read a lot of articles, but still no luck. Also all the tutorials I have found show this working with the main menu but this is working with a grid of projects that load in data with Ajax.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```html
<a id="projectAnchor" class="projectItem powerline" href="30" style="position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 5px;">
 <div id="imgContainer" name="Western Power Distribution - Brechfa Connection" href="#!30">
  <img id="projectImg" src="projectContent/30/198-th.jpeg" alt="Western Power Distribution - Brechfa Connection">
 </div>
 <img id="projectIcon" src="images/solution/powerlineIconB.png" alt="Powerline">    
  <p id="projectText">Western Power Distribution - Brechfa Connection</p>
  <div class="blueBar" id="colourBar"> </div>
</a>
```

```js
var e, p;
$(function(){
    p = $(".projectItem").click(function() {
        e = $(this);
        if(!e.hasClass('active')){
            getResults();
            history.pushState(null, null, e.attr('href'));
        }
        return false;
    });
});

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(){
    e = $('a[href="'+location.pathname.split("/").pop()+'"]');
 getResults();
});

function getResults(){
    p.removeClass('active');
    e.addClass('active');
    $.get('projectT.php', {id: e.attr('href')}, function(data){
        $('#projectContent').html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Quentin has the answer. Also, as a dirty fix you could do, history.pushState(null, null, location.href + "/" + e.attr('href'));

Comment: @LShetty — That's really dirty though since if the JS fails (as it usually will for a search engine indexing bot) the link will go to the wrong place thus rather missing the value of the history API.

Comment: @Quentin, true and I'd actually prefer href="/123.php/xx" which is safer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pushState` allows you to change the URL to *any* valid URL on the same origin.

Your link (which you use as the basis to calculate what goes into `pushState`) says to go to `30`. Your current URL is `http://www.example.com/123.php`. Standard resolution of relative URLs which don't begin with a `/` character is to discard the last path part and everything after it (`/123.php`) and then put the relative URL in its place.

You *should* write your JavaScript so that as well as changing the URI you manipulate the DOM so the resulting page is the same as you would get if you had just visited `http://www.example.com/20` in the first place.

If you actually want to go to `http://www.example.com/123.php/20` then you have to link to that: `href="123.php/20"`.

Of course, that could lead to you ending on up `http://www.example.com/123.php/123.php/30` if you follow a link to `20` and then another to `30` so you probably want to use a URL relative to the root: `href="/123.php/20"`.

Comment: Thanks very much for that Quentin! I managed to get it all working perfectly.
I didn't know that the / discarded the last path. Learnt something new today :)

Comment: It comes out of the legacy of URL syntax being based on file path syntax where "In the current directory" was a common requirement (and the equivalent is a common requirement in URLs).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have  href="30" in the a element and then you set the history to e.attr('href'). You need to pass the whole link.

Comment: If by "pass the whole link" you mean "use an absolute URL": You're wrong. It just requires an understanding of how relative URIs work.